I'm trying to add a header to the output file in pentaho but the column names from the actual data that I am writing are getting removed from file
I am trying to write some data into text file but before that I want to write about the type of the data being written to the file.
eg.
This is the data about City and country
City~Country
Mumbai~India
Berlington~USA
London~England
How to achieve this

You could potentially use couple of options
(1) use javascript step to add the header rows and then build the output string for each row and pass it the text output step. This would mean, the text file output step writes a single field.
(2) use, metadata injection to achieve, which I am not familiar with.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
